# Top then Pop Usage

Tags: c++, reference, integer, pass-by-reference, deque

I am new to C++ coming from a Python background. I am currently learning `deque` and I am getting confused on how to pop the last element and use it.

From **cppreference.com** it mentions that [`pop_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/pop_back) would remove the last element of the container and the references to the erased element in invalidated.

Example:

```cpp
std::deque<int> numbers = {1, 2, 3};
int topNumber = numbers.back(); // Return reference to top element
numbers.pop_back(); // remove the last element and now topNumber reference is invalidates
```

**Question:** how is it possible to use the top element after popping it? Does .back() return a copy in the example above, and if so why?

Answer (score 4):

> Does .back() return a copy in the example above

No, `back()` return a reference to the last value in the queue.

```
int topNumber = numbers.back();
```

The reference is assigned to an `int`. This effectively copies the referenced object into a completely different and unrelated object called `topNumber`.

When a reference to some object gets assigned to something else, that not itself a reference, a copy of the referenced object gets made, that's how C++ works (and if it's assigned to a reference, the copy is made into the assigned-to referenced object).

From that point on, the last value in the `deque` can be removed. It will be gone. But its copy still remains in `topNumber`.

Comment: thank you @sam for the prompt answer. Follow-up question, what happens if we assign topNumber like this `int& topNumber = numbers.back();`, would the behavior be undefined?

Comment: Correct, any use of this `topNumber` after `pop_back()` will result in undefined behavior.